# Loopback 'chat' application database relationships

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

I'm using Loopback 4.1.0 (generator-loopback@5.5.0 loopback-workspace@4.0.0).

I have an extended User model called 'Client', which holds all the information about the users.

I have a PersistedModel called 'Chat', which holds things like creation, last message.

I am trying to setup the relations between the two.

A Chat can have 2 or more members.

A Client can have none or many chats.

Ultimately, I need a way of finding out if a one-to-one chat exists between the logged in Client, and the Client being browsed.

I thought I'd cracked it, but it's just returning a blank object when I GET /Client/{ClientID}/chats

```
// client.json
...
"relations": {
   "chats": {
     "type": "hasMany",
     "model": "Chat",
     "foreignKey": "clientId",
     "options": {
       "validate": true,
       "forceId": false
     },
     "through": "ChatMembership"
   }
}....

// chat.json
...
"relations": {
   "members": {
     "type": "hasMany",
     "model": "Client",
     "foreignKey": "chatId",
     "options": {
       "validate": true,
       "forceId": false
     },
     "through": "ChatMembership"
   }
}....

// chat-membership.json
{
  "name": "ChatMembership",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "joined": {
      "type": "date",
      "defaultFn": "now"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "client": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Client",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "chat": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Chat",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to define the foreign key in the chat-membership.json